# compiz and unity - integration

Tags: 14.04, unity, compiz

Compiz sources (from launchpad) doesn't contain Unity plugin, but when I run CCSM on my UBuntu 14.04 LTS there is Unity plugin. How it works ?

Comment: As far as I know, Unity uses Compiz to draw its windows as well as all graphic decorations. That could explain something.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install Compiz Settings Manager from the Ubuntu Software Center and turn on Wobbly Windows.  I admit, I just like it personally.  If it interferees with any aspect of use, or slows it down, I'm unaware of it, and that's not just because of the speed of "my system", as this is a portable (pendrive type) ubuntu installation, and alternates primarily between a 6core 64bit gaming desktop with 8gb ram and graphics accelerator, and a 32bit netbook with 2gb ram and minimal graphics.

Since my installation is on portable media I also I boot other people's hardware to my own drive with some frequency.  The result naturally is that while I am introducing new people to Ubuntu in general, in the course of relatively mundane activities, I'm dazzling them with graphic features they are not accustomed to seeing performed on their own hardware.  In most cases, people are instantly interested in learning how to get Ubuntu themselves.